# Add elements to associative array

Tags: php

Alright so I am trying to figure out how to add data to an associative array. The array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [games] => Array
       [game] => Array
          [0] => Array
             [appID] => 12345
             [logo] => 'http://www.example.com/logo_12345.jpg'
             [name] => 'Game One'
          [1] => Array
             [appID] => 12346
             [logo] => 'http://www.example.com/logo_12346.jpg'
             [name] => 'Game Two'
          [2] => Array
             [appID] => 12347
             [logo] => 'http://www.example.com/logo_12347.jpg'
             [name] => 'Game Three'
    [userID] => 784523569852145
    [username] => 'Gamertag'
)
```

what I want to do is loop though the array and add the following elements to it so it look like this:

```
   Array
    (
        [games] => Array
           [game] => Array
              [0] => Array
                 [appID] => 12345
                 [logo] => 'http://www.example.com/logo_12345.jpg'
                 [name] => 'Game One'
                 [status] => 'active'
              [1] => Array
                 [appID] => 12346
                 [logo] => 'http://www.example.com/logo_12346.jpg'
                 [name] => 'Game Two'
                 [status] => 'active'
              [2] => Array
                 [appID] => 12347
                 [logo] => 'http://www.example.com/logo_12347.jpg'
                 [name] => 'Game Three'
                 [status] => 'active'
        [userID] => 784523569852145
        [username] => 'Gamertag'
    )
```

Comment: So to clarify for you: You wish to add `'status' => 'active'` to each of the numerically indexed elements in `$your_array['games']['game']`

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would go something like this:

```
foreach($my_array["games"]["game"] as &$game) {
    $game["status"] = "active";
}
```

The `&` is critical, as without it the variable `$game` would refer to a *copy* of the relevant array, rather than the array itself. In other words, your changes would not get saved.

Comment: Well I realized what was wrong with my loop than. I had the same loop except for the `&` and it wasn't working! Glad this was as easy as I thought and just an oversight on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$iamlazy =& the_array['games']['game'];
$n=sizeof($iamlazy);
for ($i=0;$i<$n;%i++)
  $iamlazy[$i]['status']=active;
```

Comment: Do you have a background in C by any chance? :)

Comment: this also works, but is a for next better than a for each, or would they be about the same?

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh for your example there will be no difference - for very, very big arrays, the numerically-indexed `for` will be a few percent faster than the `foreach` enumerator

Comment: @Codemonkey Older than that: I have a background in Zilog Z80 Assembler.

Comment: @EugenRieck What do you mean by big... This array can have thousands of games

Comment: Well, with thousands of games I guess you will notice a difference!

Answer (score 0):

You can add in new elements where you need them by simply using square brackets to identify the element you wish to add and assign it as per normal like this:

```
$array['games']['game'][0]['status']='Active';
```

This isn't a loop, but I am pretty sure you can work from here to make the loop itself based on your structure.